# CircuiTikZ logic gates alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to align the output of a `XOR` gate with `input 1` of a `NAND` gate like this

[image]

However, with the following code, I am not getting perfect alignment

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{circuitikz}  
        \draw
        (0,0) node[xor port] (xor1) {}
        (2,0.3) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
    ;\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve perfect alignment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
     \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[xor port](xor1) {} to
        (2,0) node[scale=1.2,nand port,anchor=in 1] (nand1) {}
        (nand1.in 2) -- (xor1.in 2|-nand1.in 2)
     ;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With another gate:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
     \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[xor port](xor1) {} to
        (2,0) node[scale=1.2,nand port,anchor=in 1] (nand1) {}
        (nand1.out) to +(2,0) node[scale=1.3,xor port,anchor=in 1] (xor2) {}    %% 3rd gate
        (nand1.in 2) -- (xor1.in 2|-nand1.in 2)
        (xor2.in 2) -- (xor1.in 2|-xor2.in 2)
     ;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually you don't have to align them as it is possible to connect them easily.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
     \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[xor port](xor1) {}
        (2,-1) node[nand port] (nand1) {}
        (xor1.out) -| (nand1.in 1)    %% connect them
        (nand1.in 2) -- +(-2,0)
     ;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I align a third gate after the NAND gate? (in the first part of your answer)

Comment: How do I draw a line from input 1 of the first XOR gate to x-coordinate of -2 (absolute) but the same y coordinate?

Comment: I want to extend input 1 backwards to x-coordinate of -2.

Comment: @Surag `(xor1.in 1) -- +(-2,0)  (xor1.in 2) -- +(-2,0)`